# Position Background Image within a Div (Center, Top etc)

Tags: css

I have a code pen project here - https://codepen.io/Daltai/pen/xxEbmde

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/06535cf158.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
</head>

<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <div class="box-1">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/59b42337b7411c6d02fdca0e/1505263754808-H3YLTDXNHRQWKXL38IMG/ThePolice_Logo.png?content-type=image%2Fpng">
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
    <span class="helper"></span>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Biography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Discography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
      <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></li>
     </ul>
    </div> <!--Box 2-->
  </nav>
</div> <!--Container-->

<div class="hero">
  <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/59b42337b7411c6d02fdca0e/1506278295231-UTV9G18YG42DF2A7JCWV/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kFwLpwhcqxzfNuBZPTq0g3kUqsxRUqqbr1mOJYKfIPR7LoDQ9mXPOjoJoqy81S2I8N_N4V1vUb5AoIIIbLZhVYy7Mythp_T-mtop-vrsUOmeInPi9iDjx9w8K4ZfjXt2dnihgU9gKGLroRAsvpywHz61e7rLscY9kQ8yq3Ldx1LvP7cJNZlDXbgJNE9ef52e8w/home_hero_01.jpg?format=2500w">
  <div class="h-heading-1">The History of The Police</div>
  <div class="h-heading-2">Biography</div>
  <div class="h-heading-3">Read More ></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
}

nav {
  height: 75px;
  width: 70%;
  background: #000;
  margin: auto;
}

.box-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  /*height: 40px; */
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  /* vertical-align: middle; */
}

.box-1 img {
/*   width: 151px;
  height: 40px; */
  max-height: 60%;
  max-width: 60%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li a, ul li i {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #d2d2d2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.box-2 {
  background: #000;
  /*height: 30px; */
  display: inline-block;
  /*vertical-align: middle; */
}

.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
}

.hero img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-position: center;
}

.h-heading-1 {
  top: 155px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.h-heading-2 {
  top: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.h-heading-3 {
  top: 280px;
  color: yellow;
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
  padding: 15px 50px;
}

.h-heading-3:hover {
  background: yellow;
  color: #000;
}

.h-heading-1, .h-heading-2, .h-heading-3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
}
```

I am trying to emulate this website - https://www.thepolice.com/

I am trying to center the image so it looks like the website mentioned above. My version shows the text across Stings head. On the website the background image is pushed up in position so that the top half of his head is hidden.

I have tried using the background-position: center property on this but to no avail. I have a feeling this is the parent container of class "hero" is causing this issue.

Your help is much appreciated.

Shane

Answer (score 0):

The website you are trying to copy seems to keep a fixed height for the image.  You can achieve a similar effect by adding a fixed height and then adding `object-fit:cover;` to the image in CSS to maintain its aspect ratio (which will then cut off Sting's head a little like on the webiste).  So like this:

```
.hero img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-position: center;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

here's a full example:

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
}

nav {
  height: 75px;
  width: 70%;
  background: #000;
  margin: auto;
}

.box-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  /*height: 40px; */
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  /* vertical-align: middle; */
}

.box-1 img {
/*   width: 151px;
  height: 40px; */
  max-height: 60%;
  max-width: 60%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li a, ul li i {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #d2d2d2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.box-2 {
  background: #000;
  /*height: 30px; */
  display: inline-block;
  /*vertical-align: middle; */
}

.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
}

.hero img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-position: center;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.h-heading-1 {
  top: 155px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.h-heading-2 {
  top: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.h-heading-3 {
  top: 280px;
  color: yellow;
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
  padding: 15px 50px;
}

.h-heading-3:hover {
  background: yellow;
  color: #000;
}

.h-heading-1, .h-heading-2, .h-heading-3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <div class="box-1">
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/59b42337b7411c6d02fdca0e/1505263754808-H3YLTDXNHRQWKXL38IMG/ThePolice_Logo.png?content-type=image%2Fpng">
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
    <span class="helper"></span>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Biography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Discography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
      <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></li>
     </ul>
    </div> <!--Box 2-->
  </nav>
</div> <!--Container-->

<div class="hero">
  <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/59b42337b7411c6d02fdca0e/1506278295231-UTV9G18YG42DF2A7JCWV/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kFwLpwhcqxzfNuBZPTq0g3kUqsxRUqqbr1mOJYKfIPR7LoDQ9mXPOjoJoqy81S2I8N_N4V1vUb5AoIIIbLZhVYy7Mythp_T-mtop-vrsUOmeInPi9iDjx9w8K4ZfjXt2dnihgU9gKGLroRAsvpywHz61e7rLscY9kQ8yq3Ldx1LvP7cJNZlDXbgJNE9ef52e8w/home_hero_01.jpg?format=2500w">
  <div class="h-heading-1">The History of The Police</div>
  <div class="h-heading-2">Biography</div>
  <div class="h-heading-3">Read More ></div>
</div>
```